# Why is my coconut seedling dying?

Tags: houseplants, watering, seedlings, palm

A couple of weeks ago I bought a dwarf coconut (*Cocos nucifera*) seedling from a nursery, all its leaves were quite green. But now, after some time on the ground, all the leaves are dead brown, only the younger leaves (closest to the apical meristem) retain a bit of green.

[image]

[image]

What am I doing? Too much water, too little water? Too much sun, too little sun?

Unlike [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/61070) I live in Brisbane, Australia, we're just entering the spring (cold nights are just around 10 to 15°C during the winter months) and there's plenty of light: the photos above were taken early in the morning, but from 10am on there's full sun light in that spot.

Comment: Welcome! Did you plant straight from the nursery, we’re they outside, in full sun, in (semi) shade…? Did the seedling have the now-brown leaves or has new (= at your place) growth discolored too?

Comment: Yes, I planted it straight from the nursery. I don't know how it was in the nursery (my wife bought it). There's no new leaves (new growth) since I bought it two weeks ago, simply all leaves became brown.